# Trouble deleting ChromaDB documents

Tags: python, database, artificial-intelligence, openai-api, chromadb

I can't seem to delete documents from my Chroma vector database. I would appreciate any insight as to why this example does not work, and what modifications can/should be made to get it functioning correctly.

```py
import dotenv
import os
import chromadb
from chromadb.config import Settings
from chromadb.utils import embedding_functions

dotenv.load_dotenv()

client = chromadb.Client(
    Settings(chroma_db_impl="duckdb+parquet", persist_directory="db/chroma")
)

embedding = embedding_functions.OpenAIEmbeddingFunction(
    api_key=os.getenv("OPENAI_API_KEY"),
    model_name="text-embedding-ada-002",
)

collection = client.get_or_create_collection(name="test", embedding_function=embedding)

from llama_index import SimpleDirectoryReader

documents = SimpleDirectoryReader(
    input_dir="./sampledir",
    recursive=True,
    exclude_hidden=False,
    filename_as_id=True,
).load_data()

collection.add(
    documents=[doc.get_text() for doc in documents],
    ids=[doc.doc_id for doc in documents],
)

print(collection.count())  # PRINTS n

doc_ids = collection.get()["ids"]
collection.delete(ids=doc_ids)

print(collection.count())  # SHOULD BE ZERO, BUT PRINTS n
```

Comment: I just tried it (August 3, 2023) and it works for me. The last line prints 0.

Comment: The doc leaves it unclear if count() includes deleted entries or not ("The total number of embeddings added to the database"). Many DBs delete by marking stuff deleted only. Can you still get() the deleted entries?

Answer (score 0):

*This might help to anyone searching to delete a doc in ChromaDB*

### Delete by ID

Get the collection, you can follow any of the steps mentioned in the [documentation](https://docs.trychroma.com/usage-guide#using-collections) like this:

```
collection = client.get_collection(name="collection_name")
collection.delete(ids="id_value")
```

### Delete by filtering metadata

```
collection = client.get_collection(name="collection_emb")
collection.delete(where={'metadata_field': {'<Operator>': '<Value>'}})
```

If you have metadata with the key `URL` and you want to delete all doc with URL equal to `www.example.com`

```
collection.delete(where={'URL': {'$eq': 'www.example.com'}})
```

Filtering metadata supports the following operators:

`$eq` - equal to (string, int, float) 
`$ne` - not equal to (string, int, float) 
`$gt` - greater than (int, float) 
`$gte` - greater than or equal to (int, float) 
`$lt` - less than (int, float) 
`$lte` - less than or equal to (int, float)

For more information on how to filter using metadata, look here in [documentation](https://docs.trychroma.com/usage-guide#filtering-by-metadata):